# SpEL on Hibernate Entity

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-rest

I have a situation where I have a @ManyToOne relationship as below,

```
public class PersonEntity implements Serializable {
  @Id
  @Column(...)
  private String personID;

  @Basic
  @Column(...)
  private String parentID;

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, targetEntity=PersonEntity.class)
  @JoinColumn(name = "personID")
  @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
  private PersonEntity parentPerson;      
}
```

As you can see in above, I have Person, whose parent is also a person. Now, in 99% of the business scenarios I only would need the name of the parent. So, accessing the entire parent object is an overkill.

So, in order to overcome that, there are three possible solutions:

1. Modify the DB table and add the parent name to the table itself.
2. Create a View to do the same job as above.
3. Create an @Transient variable of person name and then plugin the value whenever required.

Now, it is in the third context, as inspired by Spring @Projection (Spring DATA REST), I wanted to try out something like below with SpEL. But, it doesnt seem to work.

```
public class PersonEntity implements Serializable {
  @Id
  @Column(...)
  private String personID;

  @Basic
  @Column(...)
  private String parentID;

  @Transient
  @Value("#{@parentRepository.findOne(target.getParentID()).getParentName()}")
  private String parentName;      
}
```

Can someone help me in understanding why this wouldn't work? Are there any other alternatives apart from the ones listed above?

Comment: `@Value` (and SpEL) are meaningful in the context of Spring application containers, whereas Entities are managed by JPA persistence providers (hibernate in that case). Annotating an Entity with Spring annotation is therefore meaningless.

Comment: I think it depends on the context.. End of the day... they all must work together to achieve some business goal.. In my case, the data can either be accessed by a Spring Data REST component or a regular Spring component (like @Service etc..), I wanted to make sure that the code isnt repeating itself..

Comment: As noted above, your entity is not a Spring managed bean and Spring knows nothing about it.

Comment: Hi Alan.. sorry if this sounds silly.. just trying to understand the concept here.. since Spring container would be responsible for response process.. why wouldnt my SpEL be invoked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using Hibernate, you can do this:

```
public class PersonEntity implements Serializable {
  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "parentID")
  @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
  private PersonEntity parent;

  @Basic(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @Formula("select p.name from person p where p.id = parentID")
  private String parentName;
}
```

**Note**: `Formula` is a Hibernate-specific annotation.

Comment: Hi Manish.. I actually tried this.. this config throws an error like this.. Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: "@OneToOne or @ManyToOne on com.tb.ao.domain.entity.PersonEntity.parentName references an unknown entity: java.lang.String"}}

Comment: I have added your class to [a sample application of mine](https://github.com/manish-in-java/spring-data-inheritance/blob/master/src/main/java/org/example/domain/Person.java).  There is [an associated test case](https://github.com/manish-in-java/spring-data-inheritance/blob/master/src/test/java/org/example/data/PersonRepositoryTest.java).  No errors are seen.  Can you compare your code against this?

Comment: Sorry about the earlier comment.. I understood my mistake.. I need to use @Basic! Thank you for the reply!